# Помогите понять, какую ситуацию я не учел

Tags: python

Уже несколько часов сижу вроде бы над простенькой задачкой, которую можно решить простым перебором в цикле for, но в этом случае проходят 39 тестов, дальнейшие не идут по времени.
Поэтому я реализовал такой код:

```
l, r = str(input()).split()
l, r = int(l), int(r)
i = l
count = 0
while i < r:
    if r < 10:
        count = r - l + 1
        i = 10
    elif i < 10:
        count = 9 - i + 1
        i = 10


    number = '1' * len(str(i))
    i = int(number)
    while i <= r and len(str(i)) == len(number):
        if i >= l and i <=r:
            count += 1
        i += int(number)


print(count)
```

Задачка валится на 3-ем тесте, но сколько бы я тестов не придумал - ошибку так и не нашел.

Первый тест 4 7

Второй тест 10 100

Сама задача:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `1 1` приводит к нулю. Должна быть единица.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тест, приводящий ваш код к ошибке:

```
l, r = 777, 777
```

---

Можно применить простой перебор всех подходящих чисел, т.к. их всего `O(log(r))` (собственно, у вас это и сделано, только ошибка вкралась)

```
def cnt_u(l, r):
    cnt = 0
    ones = 1
    while ones <= r:
        for i in range(1, 10):
            if r >= ones*i >= l:
                cnt += 1
        ones = 1 + ones * 10
    return cnt
```

Comment: Для `ones` есть отличный термин: [repunit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit).

Answer (score 0):

Если `while i < r:` заменить на `while i <= r:`, ошибка уходит. Ошибка в обработке случая `l == r`.

Как уже правильно заметили, количество таких чисел логарифмическое. Можно забыть про оптимизации и порождать их все. Те что больше нижней границы попадают в счётчик. Цикл прерывается когда вышли за верхнюю границу:

```
def repunits():
    ''' 1 2 ... 8 9 11 22 ... 88 99 111 222 ... 888 999 ... '''
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield from range(n, 10 * n, n)
        n = 10 * n + 1


def main():
    l, r = map(int, input().split())
    c = 0
    for n in repunits():
        if r < n:
            break
        if l <= n:
            c += 1
    print(c)


main()
```